# jQuery DataTables RowReordering plugin - on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, datatables

I'm using the jQuery plugin [row-reordering](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html), which is an extension of [datatables](https://www.datatables.net). Basically it allows the user to drag and drog rows.

However, I can't find anything in their API that allows me to listen for drop events (that is, when the user completes the move of a row).

Could this somehow be solved using the datatables API or something else?

Edit: Added javascript code on request:

```
ui_actions = $('#ui_actions').DataTable({
          "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) 
          {
             $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
             ui_actions.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
              $(row).addClass('selected');
          },
          "bPaginate": false,
          "bLengthChange": false,
          "bFilter": false,
          "bInfo": false,
          "bAutoWidth": false,
          "scrollY":        $(window).height()/1.6,
          "scrollCollapse": true,
          "paging":         false,
          "autoWidth": false,
   });
ui_actions.draw();
ui_actions.rowReordering();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **NOTES**

Original [Row Reordering add-on](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering) is incompatible with DataTables 1.10 and above.

> **SOLUTION**

I have [forked the add-on on github](https://github.com/mpryvkin/jquery-datatables-row-reordering) and added support for DataTables 1.10
by using suggestions in the [comments](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/Index). Among other improvements there is `fnUpdateCallback` option that specifies callback function which will be called when row is reordered.

For example:

```
ui_actions.rowReordering({
   fnUpdateCallback: function(row){
      console.log('Row has been reordered', row);
   }
});
```

See [jQuery DataTables - Row Reordering](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/) article for more details.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sk2k28sc/) for code and demonstration.